# Meteor how to synchronize Client session variable with Server data

Tags: ajax, meteor, synchronization, publish-subscribe

I have some data stored on Client side by Session.set(...) (which then is rendered into a template).

This data is changing dynamically... on Server side, how can i synchronize it, so client would update templates any time data is changing on the server? Best method would be Publish/Subscribe, but it's designed for use with database.

this is what i end up so far:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Session.setDefault('dynamicArray', [{text: "item1"},{text: "item2"}]);
  Template.body.helpers({
    dynamicData: function(){
      return Session.get('dynamicArray');
    }
  });

  // place for code to sync dynamicArray with server

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var dynamicArray = [{text: "item3"},{text: "item4"},{text: "item5"}];

    // place for code to publish dynamicArray for client

  });
}
```

Comment: Publish and Subscribe aren't designed for database cursors, it's pretty much the contrary: Cursors are optimized for use with publication and subscription. You can still use the [Pub/Sub API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe) with any kind of EJSON-able data.

Comment: Ok, so I've found that Cursors are returned by .find() method which work on Mongo.Collection's, so in order to create cursor i would need to create Database collection first, or maybe I am wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment, you will need to creata a DynamicData Collection first, located outside the .isClient and .isServer conditionals. From there, .find() will allow you to collect data from the server in the form of a cursor, which can be iterated through using {{#each dynamicData}}. An example of how you might set up the collection and the helper is as follows:

```
DynamicData = new Collection('dynamicData'); //Sets up new Collection

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    dynamicData: function(){
      return DynamicData.find({}, {fields: {dynamicArray: [item1, item2, item3]})
    }
  });

}
```

Of course, this depends on how the document(s) you are retrieving are structured and what you are using them for. For instance, if you're only looking to return a single dynamicArray you might be better off using:

```
return DynamicData.findOne({}, {fields: {dynamicArray: [item1, item2, item3]}).dynamicArray;
```

...since this will return the array [item1, item2, item3] directly. This seems to be what you're looking for, since I had used the same method to replace an initial over-reliance on session data to sync information. Rather, the key point is to make *server* info available to the client *through* the helpers, which will bypass the need to sync via session data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for example, I will check this one, but I was hoping there will be some solution without using mongo collections ;). In my case dynamicData for every user will be different, so probably I'll need to add dynamicData for each user id i database. By the way i found another solution which may be Meteor.Stream https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-meteor-streams

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads up -- I think Meteor.Stream would be better for your use case since it seems to transfer data between clients instead of holding it in between on a server.

In any case, the above was for an e-menu, which explains the need for a database to hold information. If your use case is far more transient (e.g. a chat app) I could see Stream working out for you.